# how to format currency in displaytag

Tags: java, displaytag, number-formatting

I am getting the value of amount like 4567.00 , 8976.00 etc. Now while dispalying this value in displaytag i would like  to print it as $4567.00 instead of just 4567.00. How can i do that?
Provided i just want to use display tag. I can acheive the same thing using core:out tag.

```
$<core:out value="${variableInMyList}" />
```

---

***Answer Found [ How i did it ]***

Create  a new class:

```
public class NumberFormatDecorator implements DisplaytagColumnDecorator{
    Logger logger = MyLogger.getInstance ( );

    public Object decorate(Object columnValue, PageContext pageContext, MediaTypeEnum media) throws DecoratorException {        
        try
        {
            Object colVal = columnValue;
            if ( columnValue != null ){
                colVal = Double.parseDouble( (String)columnValue );
            }
            return colVal;
        }catch ( Exception nfe ){}
        logger.error( "Unable to convert to Numeric Format");
        return columnValue; // even if there is some exception return the original value
    }
}
```

now in display tag

```
<displaytag:column title="Amount" property="amount" decorator="com.rj.blah.utils.decorator.NumberFormatDecorator" format="$ {0,number,0,000.00}"/>
```

**Note:** we can use the MessageFormat in format attribute of displaytag:column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DisplayTab is not very JSTL or EL friendly, and doesn't support that style of formatting.  Instead, you need to extend the TableDecorator class and put a reference to it using the decorator attribute of the display:table tag.

Your decorator subclass should define a getter method for your formatted currency column, something like:

```
public class MyTableDecorator extends TableDecorator {
    public String getCurrency() {
        MyRowType row = getCurrentRowObject();
        return row.getCurrency.format();
    }
}
```

and

```
<display:table name="myList" decorator="test.MyTableDecorator">
    <display:column property="myProperty" title="My Property"/>
    <display:column property="currency" title="Currency"/>
</display:table>
```

Alternatively, you can implement the DisplaytagColumnDecorator interface, and reference that decorator from the JSP:

```
<display:table name="myList">
    <display:column property="myProperty" title="My Property"/>
    <display:column property="currency" title="Currency" decorator="test.MyColumnDecorator"/>
</display:table>
```

See [the documentation](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_decorators.html) for more information

Answer (score 9):

What do you need your class for?
You could write it as follows:

```
<displaytag:column property="amount" format="$ {0,number,0,000.00}"/>
```

Comment: How would you format the currency, if instead of a number, the type of the property is String. I tried `$ {0,string,0,000.00}` and $ `{0,String,0,000.00}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a decorator.

you would have something like

```
class myDecorator extends TableDecorator{

 public String getCurrency(){
   MyClass myClass  = (MyClass)getCurrentRow();


   return "$"+myClass.getCurrency;

 }
}
```

Check them out! http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/tut_decorators.html

If you don't want to use decorators, you could use the id attribute and JSTL

```
<display:table htmlId="list" name="mylist" id="row">

   <display:column>
    <%-- row is your current list object. row.currency calls getCurrency()
         $ goes right out to HTML
    --%>
     $ <c:out="${row.currency}"/>
   </display:column>
</display:table>
```

From [display:tag tag reference](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html)

> ***id***: see uid
>
> ***uid***: Unique id used to identify this
>   table. The object representing the
>   current row is also added to the
>   pageContext under this name and the
>   current row number is added using the
>   key uid_rowNum. Two tables in the same
>   page can't have the same uid (paging
>   and sorting will affect both). If no
>   "htmlId" is specified the same value
>   will be used for the html id of the
>   generated table

Comment: **$ <c:out="${row.currency}"/>**  as i said this is not what i want to do. But thanx for the decorator concept

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use:

```
<d:column title="Cost" property="cost" format="{0,number,currency}" sortable="true"/>
```